# ¿Cómo trabajar con Jupyter Notebook desde PyCharm?

Tags: python, jupyter, pycharm

Ya he instalado el paquete jupyter desde Pycharm, ejecutando la siguiente línea de código en el terminal de PyCharm:

`pip install jupyter`

Sin embargo, cuando abro un archivo `.ipynb` desde PyCharm, este no se abre tal y como espero y, además, cuando pincho en new file, no me aparece la opción de crear un archivo jupyter notebook.
¿Debo hacer algo más para poder abrir o crear archivos con la extensión `.ipynb`?

Comment: Hola Juan, que yo recuerde la integración con Jupyter Notebook  solo es posible con la versión profesional no con la Community. ¿Qué versión usas?

Comment: Aquí está la comparación entre ambas versiones: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: Uso la versión gratuita. Mirando el enlace veo que la versión gratuita no tiene la opción "IPython Notebook" ¿Es esta la opción que me permitiría trabajar con Jupyter Notebook desde pycharm?

Comment: Si... Necesitas la versión profesional para esto... No se si lo has probado, pero [Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder) ofrece una integración muy buena con herramientas de ámbito científico y análisis de datos (pandas, numpy, matplotlib, terminal IPython, etc) y tiene un pluging que permite trabajar con NoteBooks desde el mismo IDE: [spyder-notebook](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook)